# Pre-requsites for cognos

Tags: cognos

Can anybody guide me to know what is the basics required to learn COGNOS, whether a person who has an MBA or MIS is trainable even without any basic training on reporting tools?

Answer (score 2):

To effectively learn COGNOS' reporting tools, you should know some SQL (at the bare minimum, its syntax) and DBMS basics. You will also use some "programming" logic such as if/else statements and case statements.

More importantly, you need an intimate familiarity with the data you are reporting against, as you will need to verify your reports once you start building them.

I strongly suggest downloading the COGNOS trial with sample data and going through the install guide. Get it running in your local environment and do some testing there. COGNOS is best consumed hands-on.

Your education level has nothing to do with how you are able to comprehend and utilize a web application. I am nowhere near an MBA or MIS, and the majority of issues I have with COGNOS are related to how it aggregates data.

Javascript (jQuery, preferably) is pretty much a necessary to get more usable interfaces, so knowing that helps a lot too.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing Java can be useful if you are required to work with the SDK.  As far as SQL make sure your familiar with joins and different functions of the dialect of database you are using.  It is also important to  have a basic understanding of HTTP because your often configuring the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Cognos is a powerful tool, so once you have all configured the report authoring is fairly simple. However, based on my experience I would recommend to have the following skills:

**1. SQL**. Although you can develop lot of functionality in the Framework Manager or even in  Report Studio, mapping queries from DB is crucial.

**2. HTML**. Cognos outputs are rendered in HTML so it would help basic skills here. Besides, the layout uses lot of tables so make sure you understand those concepts well.

**3. CSS**. Behind the scenes, Cognos uses lots of CSS to styles, themes and defaults. You can even create custom themes. If you're going for a big project, make sure to backup the CSS files and modify everything from there. It is a hardache to modify styles within Report Studio as any minor change would be cumbersome.

If you master these skills, learning Cognos is not such a painful process. Check my tutos in youtube if you like: http://youtube.com/maulazyhola, I wish I had time to write more, but they got some cool stuff that would help you.

In case anything comes up you can post it here, I would be glad to help. Cheers.